# PHP scripting timing out after 60 seconds

Tags: php, ubuntu, timeout

Im currently writing a php script which accesses a csv file on a remote server, processes the data then writes data to the local MySQL database. Because there is so much data to process and insert into the database (50,000 lines), the script takes longer than 60 seconds to run. The problem I have is, the script times out after 60 seconds.

To make sure its not a MySQL issue, i created another script that enters an infinite loop, and it too times out at 60 seconds.

I have tried increasing/changing the following settings on the Ubuntu server but it **hasn't** helped:
max_execution_time
max_input_time
mysql.connect_timeout
default_socket_timeout
the TimeOut value in the apache2.conf file.

Could it possibly be an issue because i'm accessing the PHP file from a web browser? Do web browsers have time out limits?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: **UPDATE:** When I execute the script to update the database, the php **DOES** actually complete (ie all rows get added to the DB) even though i receive the gateway timeout after 60 seconds. After I receive the gateway timeout error, a couple of quick refreshes of the phpMyAdmin page shows that the php script is still executing as the number of rows in the database continues to increase. Surely this means it's not an issue with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally worked out the reason the request times out. The problem lies with having virtual server hosting.

The request from the web browser is sent to the hosting server which then directs the request to the virtual server (acts like a separate server). Because the hosting server doesn't get a response back from the virtual server after 60 seconds, it times out and sends a response back to the web browser saying exactly this. Meanwhile, the virtual server is still processing the script.

When the virtual server finally finishes processing the script, it is too late as the hosting server has already returned a timeout error to the front-end user.

Because the hosting server is used to host many virtual servers (for multiple different users), it is generally not possible to change the timeout settings on this server.

So, final verdict: The timeout error cannot be avoided with virtual hosting. If this is a serious issue, you may need to look into getting dedicated server hosting.

Comment: In case you are in that situation, one workround could be to make sure that the script sends some dummy data every now and then to keep connection alive.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and least intrusive way to get over this limit is to add this line to your script.

Then you are only amending the execution time for this script and not all PHP scripts which would be the case if you amended either of the 2 PHP.INI files

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time',  -1);
```

When you were trying to amend the `php.ini` file I would guess you were amending the wrong one, there are 2, one used only be the PHP CLI and one used by PHP running with Apache.

For future reference to find the actual file used by php-apache just do a

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And look for `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion however changing the max_execution_time doesn't help. As mentioned, i have already tried changing the various timeout variables mentioned in the original post. I believe they are being changed successfully as when i run phpinfo(), all the values are updated.

Comment: Is it possible to run the script from the command line. There is no limit if run using the CLI

Comment: Is there any other information in the `php error log`

Comment: If i run the script from the command line, i no longer get the timeout which is a step in the right direction! However i would prefer to call the script from the web browser as i want to set up a web interface.

Comment: I checked the the log file and did some testing and noticed the following:  
if i set the max_execution time to 100 seconds and run the script, the webpage stops trying to load after 60 seconds (error 504 - gateway timeout). if i check the log file immediately after this error, there is no log in the log file. However, if i wait another 40 seconds and check the log file again there's an entry that states 'PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 100 seconds exceeded'

Comment: Do you have a Virtual Host defined for the site in question??

Comment: Sorry i'm not exactly sure. I'm using codeanywhere cloud IDE. Through Codeanywhere, i have set up a php development box (vitual ubuntu server). 
Thanks for all your help thus far. Please see the update i added in the comment section of the original question. I'm starting to think it doesnt have anything to do with php...

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

Your problem should come from the PHP file and not the web browser accessing it.

Did you try putting the following lines at the beginning of your PHP file ?

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set ('max_execution_time',  0);
```

PHP has 2 configuration files, one for Apache and one for CLI, which explains why when running the script in command line, you don't have a timeout. The phpinfo you gave me has a max_execution_time at 6000

See [set time limit documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Create a new page called phpinfo.php, only put <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it and paste us the result.

Comment: [link to html output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwes4x5fdw24qvn/phpinfo%28%29.html?dl=0)  
Here's the output from phpinfo() in a separate script.

Comment: Ok. Try to add ini_set ('max_execution_time',  0); or ini_set ('max_execution_time',  -1); next to set_time_limit(0); in your file. I never update the .ini file directly because you end up mixing the apache and the cli one all the time.

Comment: Adding these lines didn't help. I still get a gateway timeout error after 60 seconds. As i mentioned, i've already tried changing the set_time_limit and max_execution_time. I tried setting them to very large values as well as 0 and -1. is there some other server settings that define when a gateway timeout is returned?

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS8, the below settings worked for me:

```
sed -i 's/default_socket_timeout = 60/default_socket_timeout = 6000/g' /etc/php.ini
sed -i 's/max_input_time = 60/max_input_time = 30000/g' /etc/php.ini
sed -i 's/max_execution_time = 30000/max_execution_time = 60000/g' /etc/php.ini
echo "Timeout 6000" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Restarting apache the usual way isn't good enough anymore.  You have to do this now:

```
systemctl restart httpd php-fpm
```

Synopsis:

If the script(PHP function) takes 61 seconds or above, then you will get a gateway timeout error.  The term **Gateway** is referred to as the **PHP worker**, meaning **the worker timed out** because thats how it was configured.  It has nothing to do with networking.

php-fpm is a new service in CentOS8.  From what I gathered from the internet (I have not verified this myself), it basically has executables(workers) running in the background waiting for you to give it scripts (PHP) to execute.  The time saving is the executables are always running.  Because they are already running you suffer no start-up time penalty.